# ASP.NET Response.Redirect problems

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

Recently, I hav a new Web project, it's simple, nothing hard, but has some "problems" that i never seen before.

The idea it's simple.

One page (**A.aspx**) call to anoher page (**B.aspx**). The 2 pages are in the same directory.

B.aspx is shown. When the work it's finished on B.aspx, this execute a Response.Redirect to A.aspx.

Now, something that I don't know is happening, because, redirect to A.aspx, **but the url is B.aspx**...and then the page A.aspx seen, but any buttom of function work.

**The code:**

A.aspx

```
protected void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   Response.Redirect("B.aspx", false);
}
```

B.aspx

```
private void GoBack()
{
      Response.Redirect("OfficeDetail.aspx", false);
}
```

And nohing more...

Someone know what's happening?

PS: **I'm using jquery mobile**, I don't know if it can provoque any problem, but is the first time that I have this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Is there more code in b.aspx? Without seeing more it's really tough to tell what's going on. It almost sounds like you're using a server.transfer instead of a response.redirect from what you're describing.

Comment: No, only the code that you see here.

Comment: are you using jquery mobile ajax navigation? I think is better to use MVC to work with JS frameworks. The integration with web forms can be difficult and not natural

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this. The problem is that I'm not using **data-ajax="false"** attribute on the page.

```
<form id="frmMain" runat="server" data-ajax="false"></form>
```